# Read color value from INI file

Tags: inno-setup

I want to change the header background color -  `WizardForm.MainPanel.Color`.
I tried to read the color value (clWhite) from ini file, with no success. 
I guess it's because `WizardForm.MainPanel.Color` can't receive a string value, I use `GetIniString` to get the value from ini.
Is there a way to read color value from ini?
If not is there a way to convert string to value?

Comment: Store `TColor` values as integers. Or you can write a bunch of code that will translate color constant strings into the `TColor` type since there is no such function at this time.

Comment: 10x, TLama i'll try it

Answer (score 0):

There is [`no built-in function`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13001640/960757) to convert color string to `TColor` value. Even though the answers in that thread shows how to make such function, none of them includes conversion from color constants (values like `clWhite`, `clBlue` etc.). That's because you would need to declare a series of constants for all the color constants (which is not impossible, but in many cases unecessary).

If it's not too late and you have a free hand in format in which you'll store the colors, I would suggest you to use integer type. You may use (code from) these helper functions I wrote for you:

```
[Code]
function SetIniColor(const FileName, Section, Key: string;
  Value: TColor): Boolean;
begin
  Result := SetIniInt(Section, Key, Value, FileName);
end;

function GetIniColor(const FileName, Section, Key: string;
  Default: TColor): TColor;
begin
  Result := GetIniInt(Section, Key, Default, Low(Result), High(Result), FileName);
end;
```